# Javascript currency divider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Actually my problem is very easy but I didnt make it 
So my inputs are like that: 165.000,00$ and my diveder 1.5 and result expected 110.000,00$ but when I try it comes 110,00 how can I show  like that 110.000,00 (we can ignore symbol)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're just having a problem with it not adding the two decimal points afterwards, right?  You'd probably be looking for something like this: [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you for anwser,
No actually my problem is that for example;
165.000,00/1.5 = 0.00
165.000/1.5 = 110.00
So I this result should be like 110.000 isn't it?

Comment: Actually ı found answer. sorry and thanks Kirkland.
  var plan = parseFloat(salePrice.replace(",00","").replace(".","") / markup);
  we have to remove all comma and periods